# WordPress Upload Speed

Tags: uploads

I have two instances of WordPress running on the same sever with the following details:

### First WordPress

- Version 4.4.5
- Multisite

### Second WordPress

- Version 4.6.1
- Single site

The problem I'm facing is that when I upload a mp3 file, that has a file size of 55.52 MB, it takes literally 10 seconds to upload it to the first wordpress but it takes 4-5 minutes to upload the same file to the second wordpress.

Anyone has any clues where the delay in the upload comes from? I'm uploading both files from the same internet connection and I've tried uploading them many times and the second instance is always a lot longer than the first instance.

## UDPDATE #1

I've tried creating a third instance of WordPress by running the fresh installation of 4.6.1 on the same server and the upload speed is still slower than the first instance.

Not sure if this has something to do with it but, the first instance that has the highest speed is located at the apache server whereas the two other instances are subdirectories in the first one.

Here's the file structure:

```
- public_html  
-- WordPress instance 1  
--- staging (WordPress instance 2)  
--- wptest (WordPress instance 3)
```

### UPDATE #2

I've installed a fourth instance of WordPress (4.4.5) which is the same version as the first instance, and yet, the upload speed is still slower. To be exact, I started the upload on the new instance before the first one, and the first one finished before when the fourth instance was still at 30-35%.

I've also tried switching the third instance (4.6.1) to a multisite, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: maybe it is related, maybe not a bad htaccess can be a problem, but you can test it by adding a subdomain or even better a dummy domain instead of directories

Comment: @MarkKaplun Sorry, I forgot to mention I am running the three instances with three subdomains.

Comment: each with its own vhost? in that case it should not matter, at least not in any obvious way

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yes each has it's own vhost. I have no idea why it's uploading much faster on the first instance...

Comment: did you try to install 4.4 on a subdomain as well? their might have been changes .... grr there were changes in the wrocess images on upload which might be related

Comment: @MarkKaplun I'll try it now and let you know as soon as I finish the tests!

Comment: ... can also be something related to MS, but I doubt it

Comment: @MarkKaplun Please take a look at my last update!

Comment: In that case it is unlikely to have anything to do with wordpress and more with your server config.... any chance the directories are on other disk, maybe network mapped? anyway, not sure that this is the right site in which people will be able to help you :( maybe supreruser is a better place